# Why does the lines count differently using two different way. to load text?

Tags: python

```
import pathlib

file_path = 'vocab.txt'
vocab = pathlib.Path(file_path).read_text().splitlines()
print(len(vocab))

count = 0
with open(file_path, 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:
  for line in f:
    count += 1

print(count)
```

The two counts are 2122 and 2120. Shouldn't they be same?

Comment: It's impossible to say exactly without access to `vocab.txt` - but apparently, `.splitlines()` and the file object iterators have different opinions on where the lines end. This could be due to some weird mixed line ending (LR/CRLF) in the file, or something similar. You could capture the results in a list in the second bit, and compare the lists - see where the difference sits.

Comment: Try adding `encoding='utf8'` to the `read_text()` call.

Comment: @Grismar this was my thought, too. How many lines should the file have? What does `wc vocab.txt` return?

Comment: share `vocab.txt` so that we check that too

Comment: I just try and got exact same result with one of my `test.txt` file. So there may be issue with your txt file

Comment: encoding doesn't help. wc give the lesser, 2120

Comment: what does `print(len(f.read().splitlines()))` give you?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga 2122, same as read_text().splitllines()

Comment: @Grismar that's exactly what's going on, `splitlines` considers more delimiters than the file object

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So, looking at the documentation for [`str.splitlines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines), we see that the line delimiters for this method are a *superset* of "universal newlines":

> This method splits on the following line boundaries. In particular,
> the boundaries are a superset of universal newlines.

| Representation | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `\n` | Line Feed |
| `\r` | Carriage Return |
| `\r\n` | Carriage Return + Line Feed |
| `\v` or `\x0b` | Line Tabulation |
| `\f` or `\x0c` | Form Feed |
| `\x1c` | File Separator |
| `\x1d` | Group Separator |
| `\x1e` | Record Separator |
| `\x85` | Next Line (C1 Control Code) |
| `\u2028` | Line Separator |
| `\u2029` | Paragraph Separator |

A a line for a text-file will by default use the [universal-newlines](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines) approach to interpret delimiters, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper):

> When reading input from the stream, if `newline` is `None`, universal
> newlines mode is enabled. Lines in the input can end in `'\n'`, `'\r'`, or
> `'\r\n'`, and these are translated into `'\n'` before being returned to
> the caller. If newline is `''`, universal newlines mode is enabled, but
> line endings are returned to the caller untranslated. If newline has
> any of the other legal values, input lines are only terminated by the
> given string, and the line ending is returned to the caller
> untranslated.